# About proving that $T$ compact iff $T^*$ compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

I am interested in proving that a bounded linear operator $T$ over a separable Hilbert space $H$ is compact if and only if $T^*$ (its adjoint operator) is compact.

I know that there exists other alternative proofs of this fact, but I want to know if the way which I am following can works.

**My attempt:**

I have proved before that $T$ is compact iff $\{P_nT\}\to T$. Where, if $\{e_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$, $P_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n(x|e_k)e_k$.

So, the proof of the result would be complete if I prove that $\{P_nT^*\}\to T^*$. However, this is the part that I don't see.

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if $P_nT\to T$ in norm, then as taking adjoint is isometric, we get $T^*P_n\to T^*$ in norm, so $T^*$ is a norm-limit of finite-rank operators and hence compact. The converse also follows applying the above argument to $T^*$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the first line of your proff. Concretely, I don't know why $T^*P_n\to T^*$

Comment: Take the adjoint of $P_nT$; it equals $T^*P_n$ and use that this operation preserves the norm: if $\lVert P_n T - T\rVert\to 0$, then $\lVert T^*P_n - T^*\rVert=\lVert P_n T - T\rVert\to 0$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now, I see it. Thanks